# Change the root directory D8 [docroot > web]

Tags: civimail, drupal-8

I encounter lot of issues with CiviCRM on a Drupal 8 production site :

When sending a mailing there is :
- No tracking of opened mail
- No indication of click through
There is another issue with the cron that doesn't run.

The issue might concern the root directory D8 that is the non standard **docroot** instead of the **web** directory.
This can be a direction for this issue as the installation roundearth of David Snopek's. It is based (or used to be) on the **web** directory

What is the best practice to move the root directory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal itself doesn't care about its folder name (at least, not that I've found).  CiviCRM cares, and so does Composer.

- When you rename your folder, find the `installer-paths` section in `composer.json` (in the webroot) and change `docroot` to `web` there.
- You'll also need to change all instances of `docroot` in civicrm.settings.php.
- Rebuild your Drupal cache and flush Civi caches as well.
- If you have absolute paths (that is, not using tokens like `[cms.root]`) in Civi's `Administer » System Settings » Directories` or `Administer » System Settings » Resource URLs` menus, change those too.
- Of course, don't forget to change your web server configuration :)

Comment: Thank you Jon, this helps me ;-). I have a more standard configuration of D8 this way.